# Auto margin with block element in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have been trying to create LI elements with float left and an image (as a "block") inside of them.
The code works fine in all browser, except for IE 7 (and 6), where the LI are organized vertically instead of horizontally.
What should I change in order for the code to work well in IE7?
(you can find the code at http://jsbin.com/ilexa/edit as well) .

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.2.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">

<style>
ul {
    width:700px;
}
li {
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
}
li img {
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto ;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" /></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it necessary to have the `<img>` as block? Can't the spacing be completely handled by the `<li>`? An alternative could be to declare also `<img>` as `float: left` - or perhaps even `inline-block` (see [Block-level elements within display: inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608172/block-level-elements-within-display-inline-block)).

Comment: @Matrin - I need <img> as a block since I am inserting more stuff in the LI later on (I did not include it in the source to make it simple). Why should the "block" attribute cause this problem ? (Gidi)

Comment: I suspect IE follows the "standard" block layout of allowing one block per line, despite it being wrapped in a float. Try setting `float` on the image itself and keep it block - does that help?